# Using .NET 4.5 features by running inside .NET 4.5, but compiling against .NET 4.0

Tags: .net

So I want to use a new API available in .NET 4.5 -- I always run in a .NET 4.5 process, but our compiler infrastructure uses .NET 4.0 compiler.

Is there some late-binding code we can use to resolve an API function?

Comment: I guess reflection would do the job.

Comment: thought so as well, i should give it a try. I suppose I could cache the function.

Comment: You can use reflection to obtain a delegate once. Calling that delegate is relatively cheap.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea. You may run into issues where .NET4 compiler does not know about .NET 4.5 specific features. I would recommend keeping things simple and just use .NET4.5 compiler. It can compile both .NET4 apps and .NET4.5.